# How do I customize or add more fields to FlatList, ListItem apart from "title" and "subtitle"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to render some data from an api using react FlatList, ListItem each doc has a number of fields but ListItems only give me an option for "title" and "subtitle" is there anyway to customize and add more fields?

I checked the documentation and other examples but all I see is "title" and "subtitle"

```
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem

                title={`${item.origin} - ${item.destination}`}
                subtitle={item.date}
                subtitle1={item.price}
                seats={{seats:item.status}}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}

        />
      </List>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to display more fields on the render than just "title" and "subtitle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using View within the render item. And you can apply styles to format your title text and etc.

```
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View>
                <Text>`${item.origin} - ${item.destination}`</Text>
                <Text>{ item.date }</Text>
                <Text>{ item.price }</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item._id}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}

        />
      </List>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, though i had to brace the from this `item.date` to `{item.date}`

Comment: You are welcome. I will alter the answer. By the way, please mark the answer as right.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add additional fields to the `<ListItem/>` itself however you could render a custom component via the [`leftElement`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#leftelement) prop (rather than a single string) to allow the display of additional data:

```
<ListItem leftElement={() => (<View>
        <View>{item.origin}</View>
        <View>{item.destination}</View>
        <View>{item.status}</View>
        <View>{item.price}</View>
    </View>)}
    subtitle={item.date} 
    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }} />
```

There are also a number of other props avalible to you such as [`rightElement`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#rightelement) or even [`rightTitle`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#righttitle), [`rightSubtitle`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#rightsubtitle), etc, which you can use in the same way to render custom react elements that display the additional data you have.